# Set height and width dynamically for page/section in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, height, width

I am using crystal report for printing details. I have two issues while printing.

1. Set height/width dynamically for section details

I want to change the height and width for the section dynamically through code. This height and width will come from user settings so I need those to be dynamic. When I checked, there is a option to set the section height programmatically but its not working. I am using the below code to set the section height

```
ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
Section section = rd.ReportDefinition.Sections["Section3"];
section.Height = 1;
```

When I use this code, it gives me error "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The section height is not valid."

I also want to set "Gap Between Details" dynamically. Is it possible?

2. Set page content height dynamically

I want to set the page content height dynamically. We can set the page height and width from **Design -> Page setup -> Page options -> Set Horizontal and Vertical values**.

What is happening in my case is, I am using crystal report tp print barcodes. When the page height is big, it prints empty barcodes which I dont want. I want to set the page content height based on the number of barcodes I am going to print. How can I do this?

Can anybody help me solve these two issues?

Answer (score 0):

I was finding how to resolve this question. For me, this works:

```
ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
rd.ReportDefinition.Sections["Section5"].Height = 1000;
```

Try this, ok?

Answer (score 0):

I added a formula field called `AutoHeight` and a parameter field called `Height` then I put this code inside the formula:

```
Local StringVar height = "";
Local NumberVar i;
For i:=1 to {?@Margin} do (
    height := height + Chr(10)+Chr(13)
);
height
```

The final step is to place my `AutoHeight` formula in the section I want to control with the property `Can grow` checked